# How to solve this recurrence relation: $T(n)=n⋅T(\sqrt n)+O(1)$?

Tags: recurrence-relations

How to solve this recurrence relation: $T(n)=n⋅T(\sqrt n)+O(1)$?
I tried to use telescoping to substract, but I get stucked..
$T(n) = nT(\sqrt n)+ O(1)$  
$T(n) = nT(\sqrt n) + c$
$T(n) = n(\sqrt nT(n^{1/4}) + c)+ c$
$T(n) =n^{3/2}T(n^{1/4}) + nc+ c$
$T(n) =n^{3/2}(n^{1/4}T(n^{1/8}) + c) + nc+ c$
$T(n) = n^{7/4}T(n^{1/8}) + n^{3/2}c + nc+ c$
$T(n) = n^{7/4}(n^{1/8}T(n^{1/8}) + c) + n^{3/2}c + nc+ c$
...

Comment: what is the domain of $n$? For instance, $T(1)$ is definitely not well-defined

Comment: Hi, it is O(1). Thanks for pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

So this is a pretty crummy bound, but it's something... There's only one step that isn't sharp, and maybe someone else can help tighten it. My guess is that there's no way to be both tight and closed form, though :/

$T(n) = n T(n^{\frac{1}{2}}) + O(1)$

Substitute $n = 2^{2^k}$

$T(2^{2^k}) = 2^{2^k} T(2^{2^{k-1}}) + O(1)$.

Set $S(k) = T(2^{2^k})$

$S(k) = 2^{2^k} S(k-1) + O(1)$

But we know how to solve this!

$S(k) = 2^{2^k} + 2^{2^k} \cdot 2^{2^{k-1}} + 2^{2^k} \cdot 2^{2^{k-1}} \cdot 2^{2^{k-2}} + \ldots + \Pi 2^{2^i}$

In "closed form":

$S(k) = \sum \limits_{i=0}^k \prod \limits_{j=0}^i 2^{2^{k-j}}$

Now, if we want the bound to be *clean*:

$S(k) \in O \left ( k*2^{2^{k+1}} \right )$

Substituting back in, we see

$T(n) \in O \left ( n^2 \log(\log(n)) \right )$

Unfortunately, the wild overestimation really shows - this bound is awful.

If we instead substitute without the overestimation, we retrieve

$T(n) \in 
O \left ( 
\sum \limits_{i=0}^{\log(\log(n))} \prod \limits_{j=0}^i n^{2^{-j}}
\right )$

A decidedly ugly bound.

If we try to clean it up, noticing $\prod \limits_{j=0}^i n^{2^{-j}} \approx n^2$ for large $i$, we again recover

$T(n) \in O \left ( n^2 \log(\log(n)) \right )$

---

Hope this helps ^_^